# Memory limit exceeded on Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm testing an quite large query that uses a table from another pretty complex view (can't save as a table as I don't have the needed permission) on Google BigQuery. And sometimes my browser page is crashing because "Out of memory" error.

I'm quite sure that the problem is the execution details tab, because the amount of steps performed. Is there a way to disable saving this information?

Comment: could you provide how much data your query is consuming? This information is available in top right of the BQ query editor. Also could you share the relevant screenshot to understand your issue better?

Comment: It was consumming only 287MB. I can't seem to reproduce the error today, the BQ editor is only getting really slow. But the Microsoft Edge browser only showed an error page without any error code, written "Out of memory" and try reloading or something below

Comment: This error doesn't seem to be concerned with BQ, but is rather related to your browser's memory. You can try clearing the cookies and cache memory, or follow this [doc](https://windowsreport.com/edge-error-code-out-of-memory/) which explains this error. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I already did that and didn't work. I can see on the task manager that most of the memory usage is in the BQ search tab and it only spikes after running a query and keeping the results on the page. It's consuming ~5Gb of ram with a query that only process ~290MB, but that has over 200 steps on the execution details

Comment: could you try BQ [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) and see if the issue persists?

Comment: It didn't. This solves my problem. I will be using the command line for testing querys, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, the memory issue of the browser was resolved by implementing the queries using the BigQuery command line interface.

More information on BQ CLI can be found in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool).